# Font-Awesome not showing font?

Tags: css, fonts, fontawesome-4.4.0

I'm trying to use F-A v4.7 to display some icons. I can't use the CDN because I'm building an intranet site that doesn't have access outside the network. I copied the .css files to my Content folder and the fonts to a directory in the root of the site.

I added the .css to the bundle in my MVC project. I now get the intellisense for the different F-A icons. However, when I browse to the site my sample icon doesn't show.

I looked at the page with the developer tools and I don't have any errors. I edited the .css file and replaced the fonts URL to use "~" instead of ".." but that didn't work.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('~/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.7.0');
```

I did that because my .css file is in `root\Content\font-awesome.css` and the fonts are in root\fonts\ folder. Using the tilde should make sure it uses the root and then `\fonts\` directory.

Still, no errors, no black square where the icon should be. It just doesn't show the icon. In the developer tools I can see what looks to be the correct syntax. `<i class="fa fa-print"> FA font</i>`

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Ehm, are you using only the .eot file?

Comment: You are following this method only because you are using in intranet? If so please reply.

Comment: Yes, I'm not using the CDN method because of an intranet. I'm not sure which font files it's using, I just put all of the fonts from the download into the fonts folder.

Comment: You should really implement all font types and not only the .eot - next i would check if your console reports any errors. If every font loads fine than the icon should also appear.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the entire font-awesome and use it inside your project by using link as as usual

Here is the download link : http://fontawesome.io/assets/font-awesome-4.7.0.zip

no need to create it manually

Your `<i class="fa fa-print"> FA font</i>` would work fine

Comment: That is what I did. I downloaded and unzipped the files. I put copied the font-awesome.css file into my \Content\ folder and all of the fonts into my \fonts\ folder.

Comment: you should not change the content inside the folder. just keep the folder in your project and use it.. you can change the font-awesome folder name. It is better to use like that.

Comment: "just keep the folder in your project and use it" -what does that mean?  what is the folder? what is "just use it" i.e. how do you refer it?

Answer (score 0):

Personally I wouldn't use @font-face just link directly to your font awesome file in the head of your page before including the css file like so:

```
<link href="/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: the @font-face is in the font-awesome.css file. I'm building this in an MVC project and it uses a bundle to download all the CSS files at once. It also puts them in the <head> where it needs to go. So, ultimately it puts a link like you have.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

When I checked the network tab in Chrome I saw a `.woff2` file was downloaded. Some web servers don't have the mime-type for `.woff2` but the http status was 200, so that wasn't the problem.

On a hunch I decided to delete the part that makes the browser download the `.woff2` file in `font-awesome.css`, and... suddenly all icons showed up!

So apparently, either something is wrong with the `.woff2` file or the browser (I am using Google Chrome 56).

But as a temporary workaround you can delete this part from the `font-awesome.css`:

```
url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0') format('woff2'),
```